# Postgresql dynamic query to aggregate data from tables not inserting data in temp table

Tags: postgresql, function, dynamic-sql

I have created a function to insert data in "demo" table of different schema in temp table. The schema name from different tables are stored in "company" table with column name "com_name". Here is the function i have created to insert the data in temp table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_schema_select (OUT name CHARACTER(15), OUT id VARCHAR, OUT company CHARACTER(10), OUT salary VARCHAR, OUT car CHARACTER(10)) 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  var_schema_name VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  TRUNCATE TABLE public.temp;
  FOR var_schema_name IN            
    SELECT com_name FROM public.company
  LOOP  
     EXECUTE'INSERT INTO public.temp SELECT name, id, company, salary, car  FROM '||var_schema_name||'.demo';
  END LOOP;
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM public.temp;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It is not throwing any error but it is not not inserting data in "temp" table after calling the function. Let me know if you find any error in the function.

Comment: are you committing the INSERT ?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Even after committting the insert it is not updating the record. and i am not getting any error but it is not inserting the record in "temp" table.